# Adding methods to resource routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to add methods to my resource routes that have a parameter. If I create one without a parameter it works find, but when I try to add a parameter it doesn't work.

Here's the code

```
Route::get('temp_user/activate/{id}', 'TempUserController@activate');
Route::resource('temp_user','TempUserController', array('only' => array('index','create','store')));
```

The above code doesn't work, but I need to pass a parameter to my method. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works fine here. To not create a new controller I just used and old one:

```
<?php

class StoreController extends Controller {

    public function activate($id)
    {
        return 'activate '.$id;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return 'index';
    }   

    public function create()
    {
        return 'create';
    }   

}
```

Using routes:

```
Route::get('temp_user/activate/{id}', 'StoreController@activate');
Route::resource('temp_user','StoreController', array('only' => array('index','create','store')));
```

After executing

`php artisan routes`

I get

```
|    | GET /temp_user/activate/{id} |                   | StoreController@activate | |  |
|    | GET /temp_user               | temp_user.index   | StoreController@index    | |  |
|    | GET /temp_user/create        | temp_user.create  | StoreController@create   | |  |
|    | POST /temp_user              | temp_user.store   | StoreController@store    | |  |
```

And browsing:

```
http://172.17.0.2/temp_user/create

http://172.17.0.2/temp_user/activate/1

http://172.17.0.2/temp_user
```

Everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks you were right. I found out what I was doing wrong. I was using the URI class and that's not available any more. That's what was causing the error. Now everything works good. Thanks.